# ECS fargate deployment got stuck and failed to deploy ECS Service

Tags: docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am new to ECS and I am trying to deploy it with Cloudformation.

I was making the following cloudformation template by looking at the documentation and some examples I found from blogs and some articles.

However, for some reason, it got stuck in updating one of the resources and eventually timed out.
I am not sure why it gets stuck and fails.

Can someone spot the mistake I am making?

For now, my goal is to deploy and see the app on the internet. I am not really looking for the advanced configuration.
I also pass the ecr url to this upon deployment aws cli.

Thank you in advance.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  ECS Service

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: alpha
    AllowedValues:
      - alpha
      - beta
      - production
  ECRDockerUri:
    Type: String
    Default: <url for ecr repo> 
  ContainerPort: 
    Type: Number
    Default: 8080

Resources:
  LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub "${Environment}-fake-user-api-logGroup"
      RetentionInDays: 30

  ECSCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Cluster'
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Sub "${Environment}-MyFargateCluster"

  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub "${Environment}-${AWS::AccountId}-ExecutionRole"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'

  ECSService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub "${Environment}-${AWS::AccountId}-ECSService"
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DesiredCount: 1
  
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Sub "${Environment}-${AWS::AccountId}-Container"
          Image: !Ref ECRDockerUri
          Memory: 1024
          Essential: true
          DisableNetworking: false
          Privileged: true
          ReadonlyRootFilesystem: true
          Environment: 
            - Name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              Value: !Ref Environment
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
              HostPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
              awslogs-region: ca-central-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through your CFN stack and found some things missing. I noticed that your Cluster name is **ENV-MyFargateCluster** so I am assuming your goal is to create a fargate service. To run a fargate service, you need to provide the networking configurations and notify that you want to create a Fargate service by specifying the Launch Type. Plus Fargate tasks cannot be Privileged.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-privileged

Below is my snippet of the code :

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: |
  ECS Service
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: alpha
    AllowedValues:
      - alpha
      - beta
      - production
  ECRDockerUri:
    Type: String
    Default: 'image'
  ContainerPort:
    Type: Number
    Default: 80
Resources:
  LogGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub '${Environment}-fake-user-api-logGroup'
      RetentionInDays: 30
  ECSCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Cluster'
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Sub '${Environment}-MyFargateCluster'
  ExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub '${Environment}-${AWS::AccountId}-ExecutionRole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'
  ECSService:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Service'
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub '${Environment}-${AWS::AccountId}-ECSService'
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DesiredCount: 1
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - sg-XXXXXXXXXX
          Subnets:
            - subnet-XXXXXXXXXX
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    Properties:
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Sub '${Environment}-${AWS::AccountId}-Container'
          Image: !Ref ECRDockerUri
          Memory: 1024
          Essential: true
          DisableNetworking: false
          Privileged: false
          ReadonlyRootFilesystem: true
          Environment:
            - Name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              Value: !Ref Environment
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
              awslogs-region: ca-central-1
              awslogs-stream-prefix: test
      Cpu: '1024'
      Memory: '2048'
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
```